# Lightweight Java compression library?

Tags: java, compression

I'm looking for a Java compression library that:

- is good for XML
- has a small footprint
- is fast (rather than achieves high compression ratio - speed is more important)
- easy to use

What do you guys suggest?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by an XML compression library.

Comment: do you mean minimize (stripping all the blanks, etc) or compression (like zip or rar)?

Comment: minimize would be a good start, though general compression that meets the requirements would be better - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are XML minifiers, but for compression, XML is just plain text, very verbose and repetitive, but still only plain text. You will have to look at something like [gzip](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html), or any other [general compression library](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) and try them, there is no such thing as an XML specific compression library.

Answer (score 2):

Java has some built in classes that can be used for the type of compression you're contemplating.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html

Answer (score 0):

As to basic Java compression libraries, you can check out [jvm-compressor-benchmark](https://github.com/ning/jvm-compressor-benchmark); two leading candidates in very-fast category would be Snappy-java and LZF -- former is fastest as it uses fast C codecs via JNI, and latter is fastest of pure Java codecs. Both work well for XML; while they don't get quite as good compression ratio as gzip (deflate), they are significantly faster: compression is typically 3-5x faster, and decompression 1.5 - 2x faster.